# How to use reclassify tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, reclassify

I have a model which buffers line features by a variable and then rasterizes them. I then need to reclassify before I am finished processing.

My issue is that I cannot access the values to reclassify in the model because they have not been created yet...  I have tired to use the add field button in the tool and generalize the reclassification I need (very simple - nodata is 0 and all values 0 - 100 are 1 so I get 0 or 1 in my raster...

Comment: can you include a screenshot of your model so far?

Comment: When creating the model, try executing one step at a time until you need to reclassify.  In the reclassify window, fill all fields with appropriate values.  When the model inputs are changed, the fields should remain, allowing you to use fields that don't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Add Entry* selection in the Reclassify window.  The screenshot shows the values you will need to enter.

[image]